# Reading coils using JAMOD

Tags: modbus

I have written the following program to understand how to use JAMOD to access coils. Unfortunately it is throwing the error -

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:177)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:193)
at TempReader.main(TempReader.java:27)
. x2 more times 
.

java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.BytesInputStream.readUnsignedByte(BytesInputStream.java:153)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:182)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:193)
at TempReader.main(TempReader.java:30)
net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusIOException: Executing transaction failed (tried 3 times)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:197)
at TempReader.main(TempReader.java:30)
```

In the program line 27 is "trans.execute()". The coil address I am trying to read is 0x7D1 (2001) or channel 0 Data type is 2 word. -

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.io.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.util.*;

public class TempReader {

    public static void main(String Args[]){
        TCPMasterConnection con = null; 
        ModbusTCPTransaction trans = null; 
        ReadCoilsRequest rcreq=null;
        ReadCoilsResponse rcres=null;
        InetAddress addr = null; 
        int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;
        byte byteArray[]={(byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)0, (byte)182};
        try {
            addr=InetAddress.getByAddress(byteArray);
            con=new TCPMasterConnection(addr);
            con.setPort(502);
            con.connect();
            rcreq=new ReadCoilsRequest(2001, 1);
            trans=new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
            trans.setRequest(rcreq);
            trans.execute();
            rcres=(ReadCoilsResponse)trans.getResponse();
            System.out.println("Response : "+rcres.getCoils().toString());
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            con.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error of course repeats 3 times as set in ModbusTCPTransport class (I checked the class source) i.e 3 attempts before exit and program exits.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry for digging the thread. How did u get to read the slave coils? thanks

Answer (score 1):

My sample Modbus TCP ReadMultipleRegistersRequest.

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {           

         /**************************************/

        //Read And Write Register Sample
        int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;
        String refe = "4000";//HEX Address
        int ref=Integer.parseInt(refe,16);//Hex to int          
        int count = 98; //the number Address to read
        int SlaveAddr=1;
        String astr = "192.168.1.202"; //Modbus Device                  

        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(astr);
        TCPMasterConnection con = new TCPMasterConnection(addr); //the connection
        ModbusTCPTransaction trans = null; //the transaction

        //1.Prepare the request
        /************************************/
        ReadMultipleRegistersRequest Rreq = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(ref,count);
        ReadMultipleRegistersResponse Rres = new ReadMultipleRegistersResponse();

        Rreq.setUnitID(SlaveAddr); //set Slave Address  
        Rres.setUnitID(SlaveAddr); //set Slave Address

        //2. Open the connection
        con.setPort(port);
        con.connect();
        con.setTimeout(2500);

        //3. Start Transaction
        trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
        trans.setRetries(5);

        trans.setReconnecting(true);
        trans.setRequest(Rreq);
        trans.execute();

        /*Print Response*/
        Rres = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();

        System.out.println("Connected to=  "+ astr + con.isConnected() + " / Start Register " + Integer.toHexString(ref));
        count=1;
    for (int k=0;k<count;k++){
       System.out.println("The value READ: " + Rres.getRegisterValue(k));
    }       

    /****************Close Connection**************/
        con.close();
        System.out.println("\nConnected = " + con.isConnected());
        System.exit(0);//edit Java bug error


    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } 




  }//main
```

If you want to make slave try this example:

```
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.*;
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusCoupler;

public class TCPSlaveTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {


/* The important instances and variables */
ModbusTCPListener listener = null;
SimpleProcessImage spi = null;
int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;

  //1. Set port number from commandline parameter
  if(args != null && args.length ==1) {
    port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  }

//2. Prepare a process image
spi = new SimpleProcessImage();
spi.addDigitalOut(new SimpleDigitalOut(true));
spi.addDigitalOut(new SimpleDigitalOut(false));
spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(false));
spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(true));
spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(false));
spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(true));
spi.addRegister(new SimpleRegister(251));
spi.addInputRegister(new SimpleInputRegister(45));

//3. Set the image on the coupler
ModbusCoupler.getReference().setProcessImage(spi);
ModbusCoupler.getReference().setMaster(false);
ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(15);   

//4. Create a listener with 3 threads in pool
listener = new ModbusTCPListener(3);
listener.setPort(port);
listener.start();  


    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }//main

}//class TCPSlaveTest
```

Comment: can you help me with your connection because i got read timeout all the time

Comment: ok now i understand this was not the slave it was the master... can you give me a working slave example with jamod?

Comment: I not test slave mode with jamod,
I think this example so good : http://jamod.sourceforge.net/kb/tcp_slave_howto.html

Comment: yes i'm triing with this slave and your master and it stop with error code 2

Comment: Hi @ISCI. How can i use it in android without passing IPParameters? Actually, I want to pass Arduino Bluetooth MAC address and read ModBus Data from it which is constantly generated. I am done with bluetooth Pairing with my Android phone and Arduino Bluetooth  Device. But can't read ModBus Data from Arduino Bluetooth Device. Please give me some tutorial/sample code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi @Lawrance. Your project very interesting, it seem some android app has this function like this :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.inux.android.mbmaster&hl=en

Comment: @ISCI thanks for the link. I purchase this app and it works perfect to read data via Bluetooth! Can you tell me how they implement or which library they are using?

Comment: hi
can you please post me the server code for this example? Thank You!

Comment: I'm trying with this example :http://jamod.sourceforge.net/kb/tcp_slave_howto.html

Comment: can you explain how is this number to set?/4. Create a listener with 3 threads in pool
listener = new ModbusTCPListener(3);

Comment: It mean can hold 3(threads) incoming connection at the same time.

Comment: @ISCI can you help me with the master tcp? sorry for digging the thread